# Tomcat 8.5 JDBC Realm with digested salted password: authentication fails

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, hash, salt

I'm trying to get authentication running with a digested password. Unfortunately, authentication fails with 401 error.

server.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">

    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />

    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase">
            <CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler" algorithm="SHA-512" />
        </Realm>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm" 
                driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usersdb?user=root&amp;password=MySQL_Password"
                userTable="users"
                userNameCol="user_name" 
                userCredCol="user_pass"
                userRoleTable="user_roles" 
                roleNameCol="role_name">

                <CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler"
                    algorithm="SHA-512"
                    iterations="3"
                    saltLength="8"
                />
            </Realm>

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

In my database `usersdb`, there is a table called `users`, with the columns `user_name` and `user_pass`. Also, there is a table `user_roles` with `user_name` and `role_name`.

My user is called `syncuser` and it has the role `users.sync`.

I digest the password by

```
digest.bat -a sha-512 -i 3 -s 8 -h org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler MySyncPassword
MySyncPassword:5800a4431c85d7a2$3$81a3cbfe53c94b128c1a37e5101cc7d5c5c69f4b4d4262113247a6db79bb5f8bcdcf57df8b2e1980d954be4ece50c40d862c866d3c44e2fc02cd6ecebcc4a830
```

I put the whole string `5800a4431c85d7a2$3$81a3cbfe53c94b128c1a37e5101cc7d5c5c69f4b4d4262113247a6db79bb5f8bcdcf57df8b2e1980d954be4ece50c40d862c866d3c44e2fc02cd6ecebcc4a830` into my `user_pass` column.

On the bottom of the web.xml inside my project, I have

```
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  </login-config>
  <security-constraint>
    <display-name>My Magical Project Security Constraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>ServerBackend</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/SyncServlet</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>users.sync</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>users.sync</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>*</role-name>
  </security-role>
</web-app>
```

I already tried it all in the simple way with MD5 encryption, 1 iteration and 0 salt. The problem persists.

Comment: Have you tried putting clean password in the column and check if Authentication succeeds?

Comment: Yes. No success either. It turned out, the JDBC driver lib was missing.

Answer (score 0):

It just turned out, I was missing the JDBC driver library on my tomcat server. The ClassNotFoundException was not being displayed in the server console.

Furthermore, I changed the `connectionURL` in the `Realm` tag from `connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usersdb?user=root&amp;password=MySQL_Password"` to

```
connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usersdb"
connectionName="root"
connectionPassword="MySQL_Password"
```